# Confusion on the 'linear' activation in tf.keras.layers.Dense()

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

In the [explanation on activation under Arguments](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense), it says

> "linear" activation: a(x) = x.

It's confusing. Should not linear activation act like `wx+b` (if use_bias=True)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Dense` layer itself computes `y = a(wx + b)`, and what the `activation` parameter does is change the function `a` in this computation in order to have different non-linear behavior, but if you need linear behavior, the only way to "cancel out" the `a` is with the linear function `a(x) = x`, so there is no modification to the pre-activation values (the `wx + b`).